# T-SQL "<> ANY(subquery)"

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about the Any-Operator.

On Technet it says

> For example, the following query finds customers located in a territory not covered by any sales persons.

```
Use AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT
    CustomerID
FROM
    Sales.Customer
WHERE
    TerritoryID <> ANY
    (
        SELECT
            TerritoryID
        FROM
            Sales.SalesPerson
    );
```

Further

> The results include all customers, except those whose sales territories are NULL, because every territory that is assigned to a customer is covered by a sales person. The inner query finds all the sales territories covered by sales persons, and then, for each territory, the outer query finds the customers who are not in one.

But that query returns **all** customers. 
I updated a customers TerritoryID to a value that no sales.person has, but still that query returns all customers, instead of that one I expected ..

Am I missing something ?
Might it be that that article on technet is simply wrong ?
https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187074(v=sql.105).aspx (german)

There is one customer with TerritoryID = 13

Inner query result (SELECT TerritoryID FROM Sales.SalesPerson) :
4
2
4
3
6
5
1
4
6
1
1
6
9
1
8
10
7

And in table Sales.Customer is a row with CustomerID = 13, which is the one not covered by a sales-person..

Comment: The English version ( https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187074(v=sql.105).aspx ) - which we can assume is canonical, states (in reference to the code you posted): "The results include all customers, except those whose sales territories are NULL, because every territory that is assigned to a customer is covered by a sales person." - are you certain that your query is returning **every** customer, or just very non-NULL territory customer? Remember that comparison operators don't function intuitively on `NULL` values.

Comment: You have a not equal ANY row. simply put, if there are at least 2 rows in SalesPerson you will get all rows back. because one value might match but the other one won't. :) For something like this to find duplicates I would prefer to use a left join or exists.

Comment: " are you certain that your query is returning every customer"  - yes.

Comment: it says "The inner query finds all the sales territories covered by sales persons, and then, for each territory, the outer query finds the customers who are not in one" - and that outer query shows every customer (but those do have a covered TerritoryID.. and that is what I dont unterstand

Answer (score 1):

```
create table #t1
(
id int
)

insert into #t1
values(1),(2),(3)
```

As you can see,T1 has three values

now lets see,how Any Works

When 'is Equal to ' is used with any ,it works like IN

```
select * from #t1 where id=
any(select 0)--no result
```

when `Any` is used with > or <> ,`Any` means get me all the values which are greater than minimum value

```
select * from #t1 where id<>
any(select 1)--2,3

select * from #t1 where id<>
any(select 0)--1,2,3
```

If your subquery returns one value,the outer query will try to get values which are greater than inner query

Comment: I understand your example :) But I do not understand that it says : "For example, the following query finds customers located in a territory not covered by any sales persons.". .https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187074(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: .i don't have that particular db to test.plz update qstn with inner query result

Answer (score 1):

`<> ANY` means any Sales.Customer with a TerritoryID that is Greater Than or Less Than any of the TerritoryID's in the `Sales.SalesPerson`

so `TerritoryID = 13` is greater than all or your examples `(4 2 4 3 6 5 1 4 6 1 1 6 9 1 8 10 7)`, so it's included.

`<> ALL` is the equivalent of `NOT IN` so that is what you're confusing `<> ANY` with

Look at `<> ANY` as, if there are any records in the set that are not equal to the quailifier, then include it.

Answer (score -1):

The following query has the same result:

```
SELECT CustomerID FROM Sales.Customer
WHERE TerritoryID NOT IN (SELECT TerritoryID FROM Sales.SalesPerson)
```

Comment: OP is trying to understand why his statement is behaving a certain way - this doesn't help answer that.